# Java: How can I split multiple sentences in a txt file to an array and then search for individual words in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stuck on a project here, we were given a txt file with multiple sentences that have the username, hashed password and user role in it. I managed to split the sentences to individual arrays with the split function but now I'm lost on how I would search each individual sentence for a matching username/password. Any help is really appreciated.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Execute {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
        String username = "";
        String password = "";

        Authentication user = new Authentication();

        // Ask for user input
        System.out.println("Enter your username");
        username = scnr.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your password");
        password = scnr.nextLine();

        // Convert the password string to an MD5 hash
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(password.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
        }
        // Set the username and password to what the user entered
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(sb.toString());

        // open the credentials file
        try {
            fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("src/credentials.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        Scanner inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
        // inFS.useDelimiter("");

        int lineNumber = 1;
        while (inFS.hasNextLine()) {
            String fileLine = inFS.nextLine(); // declares string "fileLine" to
                                            // the next line in the file
            String[] fileLineArray = fileLine.split("; "); // turns fileLine into
                                                        // an array name
                                                        // fileLineArray
            lineNumber++; // increase line number by 1 each progression

            if (fileLineArray[0].matches(user.getUsername())) {
                System.out.println("Success");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if it helps but here's the other class.

```
public class Authentication {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Authentication(){
        setUsername("");
        setPassword("");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Also this is the credentials file

```
griffin.keyes 108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f zookeeper;

rosario.dawson 3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5 admin;

bernie.gorilla a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b veterinarian;

donald.monkey 17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3 zookeeper;

jerome.grizzlybear 3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900 veterinarian;

bruce.grizzlybear 0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7 admin;
```

Comment: Is this the exact structure of your text file?

Comment: you can split each sentence again and the iterate over the words you get and check if they are `.equal()`

Comment: have you tried

if(fileLineArray[0].equals(user.getUsername()) && fileLineArray[1].equals(user.getPassword())){
    System.out.println("Success");
}

or whatever the password index is.

Comment: split on space myString.split("\\s+");

Comment: @SedrickJefferson yes thats the structure of the txt file.

Comment: @uran when I try your code it still returns false even tho I type in the username and password correct :(

Comment: I would suggest you use java properties to store information. Java properties would easily find the username for you.

Comment: Java properties: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html  and https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: @SedrickJefferson the thing is that we can only use the material we learned during this intro course for Java, it just covers like basic arrays etc, We haven't really seen Java properties so

Comment: Okay, didn't know it was for a class.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson your comment with the split function made it work man, in combination with uran's improved code. Thanks a bunch guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (fileLineArray[0].contains(user.getUsername())) {
        System.out.println("Success");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
```

Try with contains becasue

> fileLineArray[0] is griffin.keyes 108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f
>   zookeeper

or try to make a differnt split and search by line in the file

use

> readLine()

and use a token in your file to make a better split

```
griffin.keyes-108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f-zookeeper


String[] fileLineArray = fileLine.split("-");
fileLineArray[0] will be griffin.keyes
```